# Not able to run Kafka on docker after creating image(build)

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, confluent-platform

### **Dockerfile**

```
From centos:centos6
COPY ./confluent-4.1.0 /etc/confluent-4.1.0
RUN echo 'export CONFLUENT_HOME="/etc/confluent-4.1.0"' >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin"' >>  /root/.bashrc
WORKDIR /etc/confluent-4.1.0/bin/

EXPOSE 2181
EXPOSE 8082
EXPOSE 9092

CMD ["confluent","start"]
```

---

Build Command:-docker build -f Dockerfile -t kafkademo .(Successfully build)

run command:- sudo docker run -i -t kafkademo (error)
executable file not found $PATH

Comment: As @Jakub Bujny says - just use the pre-built Docker images that exist, unless you have a specific reason for wanting to build your own.

Comment: Docker containers by default won’t read a `.bashrc` file.  Use an ENV directive to set environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your problem you can exchange your exports with:

```
ENV CONFLUENT_HOME="/etc/confluent-4.1.0"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin"
```

As when docker runs container, he doesn't respect .bashrc file.

Also I would strongly recommend using official confluent image which is on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/